# Slow MySQL Updates/Inserts/Deletes

Tags: mysql, performance

I seem to be having slow inserts, updates and deletes on all tables on a specific database with MySQL. Not a lot of data in those tables (from 2k to 20k). Small number of columns (5-10), indexes (two of them), and no duplicate index issue. I'm running MySQL 5.0.45 with MyISAM.

I run the following query and it takes about 5-7 seconds:

```
UPDATE accounts SET updated_at = '2010-10-09 11:22:53' WHERE id = 8;
```

Selects seem to come back right away.

Explain gives me the following:

```
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | accounts | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 1841 | Using index | 
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

The profiler doesn't show any significant data for anything other than a seemingly high number of context switches:

```
+----------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
| Status               | Duration | Context_voluntary | Context_involuntary |
+----------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
| (initialization)     | 0.000057 |                 0 |                   0 | 
| checking permissions | 0.000008 |                 0 |                   0 | 
| Opening tables       | 0.000013 |                 0 |                   0 | 
| System lock          | 0.000005 |                 0 |                   0 | 
| Table lock           | 0.000005 |                 0 |                   0 | 
| init                 | 0.000061 |                 0 |                   0 | 
| Updating             | 0.000101 |                 0 |                   0 | 
| end                  | 7.957233 |              7951 |                   2 | 
| query end            | 0.000008 |                 0 |                   0 | 
| freeing items        | 0.000011 |                 0 |                   0 | 
| closing tables       | 0.000007 |                 1 |                   0 | 
| logging slow query   | 0.000002 |                 0 |                   0 | 
+----------------------+----------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

This might also help:

```
+----------------------+----------+-----------------------+---------------+-------------+
| Status               | Duration | Source_function       | Source_file   | Source_line |
+----------------------+----------+-----------------------+---------------+-------------+
| (initialization)     | 0.000057 | check_access          | sql_parse.cc  |        5306 | 
| checking permissions | 0.000008 | open_tables           | sql_base.cc   |        2629 | 
| Opening tables       | 0.000013 | mysql_lock_tables     | lock.cc       |         153 | 
| System lock          | 0.000005 | mysql_lock_tables     | lock.cc       |         162 | 
| Table lock           | 0.000005 | mysql_update          | sql_update.cc |         167 | 
| init                 | 0.000061 | mysql_update          | sql_update.cc |         429 | 
| Updating             | 0.000101 | mysql_update          | sql_update.cc |         560 | 
| end                  | 7.957233 | mysql_execute_command | sql_parse.cc  |        5122 | 
| query end            | 0.000008 | mysql_parse           | sql_parse.cc  |        6116 | 
| freeing items        | 0.000011 | dispatch_command      | sql_parse.cc  |        2146 | 
| closing tables       | 0.000007 | log_slow_statement    | sql_parse.cc  |        2204 | 
| logging slow query   | 0.000002 | dispatch_command      | sql_parse.cc  |        2169 | 
+----------------------+----------+-----------------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Additional info:
It's running on a CentOS-5 VPS with 4 gigs of ram guaranteed. No index on the updated_at column and not triggers anywhere.

[New things that I tried]

1. Created a new table (using like)
   running innodb and inserted all
   records from one of the affected
   tables. (same problem)
2. Backed up the database and restored it to a
   different database within the same
   server instance. (same problem)
3. Restored that same backup to my
   local machine and I didn't have a
   problem.
4. Tried another database
   within the same mysql server
   instance that has the problem
   database and the other database (a
   Wordpress DB) ran
   updates/inserts/deletes just fine.
5. Restarted mysqld and restarted the entire server last night (same problem)
6. Updated MySQL to version 5.0.77 (same problem)
7. Deleted all indexes from one of the affected tables (same problem)

Any ideas what to look at next or what might be the issue? Seems to be more of a recent problem though I can't say when it started to show up exactly.

Comment: Is there a index on the updated_at column?

Comment: What kind of machine is this running on? On a resource limited machine (ie: not much RAM), MySQL won't be able to keep the main index in memory forcing it to be read from disk each time.

Comment: No index on an updated_at column and it's on a VPS with 2 gigs guaranteed. Another database (WordPress) on the same mysql server instance seems to handle updates/inserts/deletes well.

Comment: what is the database/table/column charset & collate ? is `update_at` part of the index? data type for `update_at` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer. That database was somehow missing the MYD and MYI files and still running. Not sure how that's possible considering that the MYD file holds the data for MyISAM tables but that was causing the slow inserts/updates/deletes.

I ran an ALTER TABLE to set the engine to MyISAM (which it already was) and it recreated those files. Updates/inserts/deletes running fast again!

Answer (score 1):

If you have variable length rows, you might need to run **OPTIMIZE TABLE** occasionally.

Comment: That locks the table. Activity is low in the db and I have a table that gets little action (2k records) showing this problem so I ran OPTIMIZE TABLE on it. No go. Same problem.

Comment: Hows the machine vitals ?  load average ?  vmstat info ?  low ram ?  lots of disk io ?  lots of other databases on the same mysql server ? Try restarting mysql ? Problem sounds really odd =(

Comment: Tried restarting MySQL earlier. All vital stats look great; it's sleeping. I also restored the most current backup into a database on my local machine. All updates/inserts/deletes are fast. Very little activity happening at this time, doesn't make sense considering that everything looks good. Locally, there's a difference with context switching: 1 vs. 7951 listed in Context_voluntary.